# Documentation for Web API in Windows Store apps (Metro apps)

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, asp.net-web-api, windows-store-apps

I remember seeing a few months ago some documentation on MSDN for accessing a Web API from within a Windows Store app, with samples, but I cannot find this page anymore, and a Google search doesn't yield a single related result for MSDN.

Anyone know where the documentation for this is?

Comment: I don't know where it on MSDN but there seems to be a downloadable sample [here](http://www.piotrwalat.net/consuming-asp-net-web-api-services-in-a-windows-8-c-xaml-app/). And docs [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2778398) and [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c25b6d/create-a-web-api-and-consume-it-in-the-windows-8-apps/) showing code but no downloadable sample...sorry it's not a direct answer (hence a comment) but hopefully those links are of some use....

Comment: Ooh, nice and easy. This will be enough to get me going. Thank you @nkvu - if you want to put that as an answer, I'll accept it. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[nkvu - moving out of the comments and into answers in case anyone else is looking for a similar thing]

I don't know where it on MSDN but there seems to be a downloadable sample [here](http://www.piotrwalat.net/consuming-asp-net-web-api-services-in-a-windows-8-c-xaml-app/). And docs [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2778398) and [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c25b6d/create-a-web-api-and-consume-it-in-the-windows-8-apps/) showing code but no downloadable sample.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the System.Net.Http namespace which includes the HttpClient is available for Windows Store apps.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.Net.Http.aspx

Comment: So, in the most basic sense, in order to connect to and authenticate users stored in a Web API all you really need for the client is a bunch of HTTP Requests?

Comment: @Jase  Ideally, yes.  APIs sometimes provide "helper" libraries, but these should be optional.